# SyntaxError: invalid syntax[plt.scatter]

Tags: python, matplotlib

I had prepared a Polynomial Regression model , everything seems alright just that there is a problem with matplotlib! I don't know what actually is wrong! Here's the code:

```
plt.scatter(X,y,color='Red')
plt.plot(X , lin_reg.predict(X),color='Blue')
plt.title('Truth')
plt.xlabel('Position')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

And here's the error:---

```
File "<ipython-input-15-697418dc1afd>", line 3
    plt.scatter( X,y,color='Red')
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: In addition to agreeing that you ought not paste code images (copy-pasting the code is the same process), the error you describe in the title isn't the error that you've shown. `np.reshape` needs two arguments, the array to be reshaped and the new shape, you've only provided one, which it has interpreted as the original array.

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with `plt` or invalid syntax.

Comment: Count your parentheses on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

according to the docs, `reshape` receives at least 2 params (you provided only one):

```
numpy.reshape(a, newshape, order='C')
where:
- a : array_like
Array to be reshaped.
 - newshape : int or tuple of ints
The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.
```